# Double tryparse return value is inconsistent

Tags: c#, .net, double, tryparse

I have a strange problem. When my custom formatted Hex value is tested with double.Tryparse it returns inconsistent results

**For example**

> `if (double.TryParse(dblValue, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double x))`

If the `dblValue = "0E-63"` the above statement returns `true`
and if `dblValue = "0E-5B"` it returns `false`
I expect both of these custom formatted hex values to return `false` in `TryParse`, so that my code handles them as not a number.
What am I missing here.

other than this double and integers are working as expected.

Comment: `0E-63` is a valid decimal number in scientific format, `0E-5B` is not. Thats why it parses the first one but not the second one.

Comment: If you use `NumberStyles.Number` then trying to parse scientific notation _would_ fail, but it's not clear if that's the intent here or not since hex values are typically parsed to _integer_ types and do not contain dashes.  Is the intent to parse the base and exponent as separate hex numbers?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Its just a custom formatted Hex value for display purposes and I want the tryparse to fail here. ``NumberStyles.Number`` did the job for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0E-63 here *is not hex* - it is 0 x (10 to the power of -63) - in the same way that 1E-03 parses as 0.001 i.e. 1 x (10 to the power of -3).

This API does not parse hex.